# Update record and then insert the same record with revision amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to update ETLDeletedatetime in the 4th row Target table and insert the revision amount  was got updated in ETLDeletedatetime?

OrderID identity (1,1) on both tables

Source table orderID 1 have been delete and I need the Target table orderID 1 to update with ETLDeletedatetime. Then I need insert new record of negative 300.00 amount in Target table

Source Table

| OrderID | Amount | CreatedDatetime | UpdatedDatetime | Deletedatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 100.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL |
| 5 | 1100.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-18 | NULL |
| 6 | 200.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Target Table

| OrderID | Amount | CreatedDatetime | UpdatedDatetime | Deletedatetime | ETLInsertdatetime | ETLUpdatedDatetime | ETLDeletedatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 100.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL |
| 5 | 1100.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-18 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-18 | NULL |
| 6 | 200.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL |
| 1 | 300.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL |
| 3 | 400.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-18 |

End goal

| OrderID | Amount | CreatedDatetime | UpdatedDatetime | Deletedatetime | ETLInsertdatetime | ETLUpdatedDatetime | ETLDeletedatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 100.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL |
| 5 | 1100.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-18 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-18 | NULL |
| 6 | 200.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL |
| 1 | 300.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-19 |
| 3 | 400.00 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | NULL | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-18 |
| 7 | -300.00 | 2022-07-19 | 2022-07-19 | NULL | 2022-07-19 | 2022-07-19 | NULL |

--Source table

```
create Table Source (
OrderID Int Identity (1,1) Primary key,   
Amount Decimal(30,2) Not Null,  
CreatedDatetime Datetime Default GetDate() Not Null,   
UpdatedDatetime datetime Default GetDate(),  
DeleteDatetime datetime)
```

--Target table

```
create Table TargetCDC (  
OrderID Int not null,   
Amount Decimal(30,2) Not Null,  
CreatedDatetime Datetime ,   
UpdatedDatetime datetime ,  
DeleteDatetime datetime,  
ETLInsertDateime Datetime Default Getdate () not Null,  
ETLUpdatedDatetime datetime default GetDate (),  
ETLDeteleteDatetime datetime)
```

--Insert source table

```
Insert INTO Source (Amount)  
values (300.00), (310.00), (400.00),(100.00),(1100.00),(200.00)
```

--Insert target table

```
Insert INTO TargetCDC (Amount)  
values (300.00), (310.00), (400.00),(100.00),(1100.00),(200.00)
```

--Delete amount 400.00 from source table

```
Delete from Source  
where OrderID = '3'
```

--Update Target table with ETLDeteleteDatetime

```
Update CDC  
set CDC.ETLDeteleteDatetime  = getdate()  
FROM Source   
full outer JOIN TargetCDC CDC ON Source.Orderid = CDC.OrderID  
where source.orderid is null
```

--Delete orderid 1 amount 300.00  from source table

```
Delete from Source  
where OrderID = '3'
```

--In one query, I need to update orderid 1 amount 300.00 with ETLDeteleteDatetime in target table and insert new record with revisal amount. This is something that I don't know.

Comment: souce and target appear to be the same??

Comment: @Harry I'm not new to this forum and had hard time add the target table

Comment: How do you know in the source table that order id 1 was deleted? are you using a trigger to capture this? What does the deleting?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It's hard delete on the source table. But, I want keep a record on target table by updated the ETLDeletedatetime. See the end goal with order 1 ETLDeletedatetime and insert orderid 7. This is kind result. Do I need to use trigger or Insert into ?

Comment: To capture a hard delete you need a trigger. Inside that trigger you need an `insert into`

Comment: Can you show your current query on how do you delete from `Source` and insert into `Target`? Also show the original state of `Source` before delete. You mention `OrderID identity (1,1) on both tables`, how do you maintain the same `OrderID` in both table for the same row ( as you said: `Source table orderID 1 have been delete and I need the Target table orderID 1`)

Comment: _To capture a hard delete you need a trigger_ alternatively a better approach is to only perform your deletes through a store dprocedure that manages all of this maintenance. Yet another option for capturing table history is to use a temporal table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Squirrel I add the query I used above.

Comment: This is just exactly what System Versioned Temporal Tables do.  I'd use those, instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
INSERT INTO [TargetCDC] ([OrderID],[Amount])
SELECT -[x].[OrderID], -[x].[Amount]
FROM (
    UPDATE [CDC]
    SET [CDC].[ETLDeteleteDatetime] = GETDATE()
    OUTPUT inserted.[OrderID], inserted.[Amount]
    FROM [TargetCDC] [CDC]
    LEFT JOIN [Source] on [Source].[OrderID] = [CDC].[OrderID]
    WHERE [Source].[OrderID] IS NULL
) AS [x];
```

Comment: Have you ever use such syntax yourself before ? You can't take the result from `OUTPUT` clause and perform an `INSERT`. You will get error like `A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.`

Comment: Yes, I used the exact statement I posted on Microsoft SQL Server - As you say yourself in that error you mention: You cannot do this in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement - which however it is

Comment: @AndreasP. your query works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `after` delete trigger. And insert into the `TargetCDC` table from the `deleted` virtual table

```
create trigger trSourceDelete
on Source
for after delete
as
begin
     insert into TargetCDC (OrderID, Amount, ETLDeteleteDatetime)
     select OrderID, Amount, ETLDeteleteDatetime = getdate()
     from   deleted
end
```

Comment: This does not handle the update and also does not negate the Amount. So at the very least you would need another update statement as well.

Comment: The trigger is for deletion, you can change to for update also. Also your description of the problem is unclear. You didn't mention anything about `negate` the amount. You can use this trigger query as a base to modify to your requirement